# How to show sample correlation is sample covariance for standardized values?

Tags: correlation, mathematical-statistics, multivariate-analysis, covariance, covariance-matrix

Given a matrix $X$ and the resulting sample correlation matrix $R$, consider the standardized observations:

$$\frac{(x_{jk} - \bar x)} {\sqrt{S_{kk}}} \quad k=1,2,...,p \quad j=1,2,...,n$$

Show that these standardized quantities have sample covariance matrix $R$.

Sample covariance is defined as:

$$\frac{1}{n} \sum\limits_{j=1}^n{(x_{ji} - \bar x_i)(x_{ji} - \bar x_k)}$$

Sample correlation coefficient:

$$r_{ik}=\frac{S_{ik}} {\sqrt{S_{ii}}\sqrt{S_{kk}}} = \frac{\sum\limits_{j=1}^n(x_{ji}-\bar x_i)(x_{jk}-\bar x_k)}{\sqrt{\sum\limits_{j=1}^n(x_{ji}-\bar x_i)^2\sum\limits_{j=1}^n(x_{jk}-\bar x_k)^2}}$$

It is also known that:
$$R (correlation) = D^{-1/2}SD^{-1/2}$$
S = variance-covariance matrix

D = sample standard deviation matrix

How do I show that for standardized quantities sample correlation is just the sample covariance?

**Attempted answer:**
For standardized variable, variance is defined as:
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_j\frac{(x_{jk} - \bar x_k)^2} {S_{kk}}=\frac{S_{kk}}{S_{kk}}=1, \quad k=1,2,...,p,$$

thus D = diagonal matrix with variance satisfies:
$$ D = I $$
and since
$$R (correlation) = D^{-1/2}SD^{-1/2}$$
we can conclude that 
$$ R=D $$

Comment: By computing $D$?

Comment: @VincentGuillemot Sorry I made a typo, should be -1/2 instead of 1/2.

Comment: @VincentGuillemot What if we do not know the last condition? How do we prove based only on knowing it's standardized quantities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variance of a standardized variable is 
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_j\frac{(x_{jk} - \bar x_k)^2} {S_{kk}}=\frac{S_{kk}}{S_{kk}}=1, \quad k=1,2,...,p,$$
and so is, therefore, its standard deviation. Hence, $D$, which is a diagonal matrix with the variances (not the standard deviations, that is given by $D^{1/2}$) on the main diagonal, satisfies $D=I$, and therefore, $D^{1/2}=D^{-1/2}=I$, the identity matrix.

Notice we do not need to subtract the sample average, as a demeaned variable has mean zero by construction: $\sum_{j=1}^n(x_j-\bar x)=\sum_{j=1}^nx_j-n\bar x=0$.

Comment: Can I say that since standardized values are centered at zero and expressed in standard deviation units. The sample correlation is equal sample covariance ? Also D^{1/2}RD^{1/2} = S -> R=S?

Comment: But how should I express this concept in terms of correlation coefficient formula?

Comment: I gave some further hints.

Comment: @christophhack I was on vacation and just got back on Tuesday. I posted an attempted answer, and I hope it not too simple. Thank you for all the guidance.

Comment: @lydias, yes, that properly uses the hints from my answer